# How to truncate a table in teradata using spark jdbc connection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I want to truncate a teradata table before loading data using spark and scala. 
I am able to load data but failed to truncate .
please guide.

Comment: How did you try to truncate and how did it fail?

Comment: i tried spark.read.jdbc(url, query, prop) where query contains s"DELETE ${database}.${table} ALL", ${database} = database and ${table} =  table

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: show error pls.

Comment: tried spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("dbtable", s"DELETE ${table} ALL").option("user", "user").option("password", "password").load() and getting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver error.

Comment: You seem to use a wrong call, spark creates a `select`. Btw, you should not show a password

Comment: indeed it is a read. there is a prepared statement approach or read the guide. pswd indeed a serious blunder.

Comment: That error means either the driver was not found in the classpath or the url is wrong. But DELETE statement is not valid within FROM clause of a SELECT, so spark.read method will fail anyway. How are you loading data? Perhaps there is an "overwrite" option.

Comment: Yes to load data , i use write method i.e df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop) because , i load records from kafka broker . Before starting my job i want to truncate the table and start loading logs from broker to teradata staging table.

Answer (score 0):

This exception "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver error" means that the Teradata JDBC Driver is not available on your classpath. You need to ensure that you have downloaded the Teradata JDBC Driver from downloads.teradata.com, unpacked the download package, and that you have listed terajdbc4.jar on your classpath.